# simple_html_dom access ul inside div

Tags: php, simple-html-dom

I'm using `simple_html_dom` for class html grabbing script, i got a problem when trying to grab ul inside a div

**HTML**

```
<div class="attributes">
      <div class="headline">test header</div>
                <ul>
                  <li>test 1</li>
                  <li>test 2</li>
                  <li>test 3</li>

                </ul>
    </div>
```

**PHP**

```
//call to function
$url = 'http://example.com';

$data = dlPage2($url,'.attributes');
echo $data;


//function

function dlPage2($href,$element) {

    $curl = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_URL, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_REFERER, $href);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);
    curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows; U; Windows NT 6.1; en-US) AppleWebKit/533.4 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/5.0.375.125 Safari/533.4");
    $str = curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);

    // Create a DOM object
    $dom = new simple_html_dom();
    // Load HTML from a string
    $dom->load($str);
$dom= $dom->find($element,0)->outertext;
    return $dom;
    }
```

above code i can grab whole `<div class="attributes">` but i need to get html of `<ul>` tag inside that div,

can someone help me to change this please

Comment: great, its working, if you can put this as answer i can select, Thanks a lot

Comment: Glad to help you :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to select `<ul>` inside `$element` by using

`$dom = $dom->find($element.' ul', 0)->outertext;`